# How to create a c# object and serialize it

Tags: c#, json, api, post, serialization

In C# I want to created JSON String or Object with the format below:

```
{
    "retailer_br_id" : "5473182",
    "retailer_external_id": "",
    "erp_invoice_number" : "INV-202302",
    "invoice_date": "2023-04-06T17:00:00.000Z",
    "status" : 1,
    "details":[{
        "sku_external_id": "TD5015151432201",
        "quantity" : "2",
        "price_per_item": "14.5"
        },
        {
            "sku_external_id": "000005020170898446",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "price_per_item": 10.50
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following, but it seems not working, it only gives me the dList value...................................................................................................................................

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Details");
dt.Columns.Add("sku_external_id", typeof(string));

//Data  
dt.Rows.Add("0000000000");
dt.Rows.Add("111111111");
dt.Rows.Add("1222222222");
dt.Rows.Add("3333333333");

Root rt = new Root();
rt.retailer_br_id = "32423432432424";
rt.retailer_external_id = "";
rt.erp_invoice_number = "PBY-202304";
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string dateString = d.ToString("Y-m-d H:i:s");
rt.invoice_date = dateString;

List<Detail> dList = new List<Detail>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Detail det = new Detail();
    
    det.sku_external_id = (string)dt.Rows[i]["sku_external_id"];
    
    dList.Add(det);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dList, Formatting.Indented);
textBox1.Text = json;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are serializing `dList`, but not `root`, this is why it show the serialized `dList`.
2. Missing assign the `dList` to `rt.details`.

```cs
rt.details = dList;
        
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rt, Formatting.Indented);
```

3. To serialize date to ISO 8601 format:

```cs
string dateString = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:sss.fffZ");
```

**Alternatives**

1. Instead of using `foreach` loop to iterate and add items into `dList`, you may achieve with:

```cs
dList = JArray.FromObject(dt)
    .ToObject<List<Detail>>();
```

2. Name the properties as Pascal Case, and use `JsonProperty` attribute to define the property name used in serialization and deserialization.

```cs
public class Detail 
{ 
    [JsonProperty("sku_external_id")] 
    public string SkuExternalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public object Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price_per_item")]
    public object PricePerItem { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("retailer_br_id")]
    public string RetailerBrId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("retailer_external_id")]
    public string RetailerExternalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("erp_invoice_number")]
    public string ErpInvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("invoice_date")]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

3. Change `invoice_date` property to `DateTime` type so it will serialize and display the format in ISO 8601, instead of defining the format manually.

```cs
rt.invoice_date = DateTime.Now;
```

```cs
[JsonProperty("invoice_date")]
public DateTime invoice_date { get; set; }
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3FpJNI)

Comment: this work for me thanks, how abount if I have to add another set of details say detail_1

Comment: i got it now i just added it on the class roor and added a new class for detail_1

Answer (score 0):

The json will only have the value of dList, because you have not assigned `rt` to the `det` object.  I am assuming that `det` has a property which can be assigned to with the value of rt e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Detail det = new Detail();
                
    det.sku_external_id = (string)dt.Rows[i]["sku_external_id"];
    det.root = rt;
    
    dList.Add(det);
}
```

if `det` does not have a property of type root, you will need to add one.

It may be that you do not want `root` to be assigned to each instance of `det` to the list.  If you want to assign it once outside the list then you would need a wrapper object eg.

```
class MyObject {
   public  Root root{ get; set; }
   public  List<Detail> dList { get; set; }
}
```

The modified code will then look like...

```
MyObject myobject = new MyObject();
List<Detail> dList = new List<Detail>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Detail det = new Detail();

    det.sku_external_id = (string)dt.Rows[i]["sku_external_id"];

    dList.Add(det);
}
myobject.root = myobject;
myobject.dlist = dList;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject, Formatting.Indented);
textBox1.Text = json;
```

Comment: Hi,  iam getting this error msg on myobject Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'restClient_0.Form1.MyObject' to 'restClient_0.RESTClient.Root' PFApi D:\API\PFApi\PFApi\Form1.cs 157 Active

Answer (score 0):

you can just use an anonymous type

```
var obj = new
    {
        retailer_br_id = 5473182,
        retailer_external_id = 0,
        erp_invoice_number = "INV-202302",
        invoice_date = "2023-04-06T17=00=00.000Z",
        status = 1,
        details = new[] { 
        new {
        sku_external_id= "TD5015151432201",
        quantity = 2,
        price_per_item= 14.5
        },
        new {
            sku_external_id= "000005020170898446",
            quantity = 1,
            price_per_item= 10.50
        }
      }
    };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

now if you want, you can convert this JSON to a C# classes online
using this link for example https://json2csharp.com/